# Download generated PDF file with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf-generation, blob

I'm trying to download generated pdf using ajax. So far i have came up with this and result was blank PDF. am i doing it wrong?

```
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('survey/download') }}",
                data: $('#frmSurveyDownload').serialize(),
            })
            .done(function( data ) {
                var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"}),
                        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(url, "new window", "width=200, height=100");
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
```

Comment: Why don't create a new hidden form and submit it?

Comment: Have you made sure your server script is generating a valid pdf file from your post data?

Comment: @passion i already tried that method. problem is i cant submit one after another request. browser getting refreshed on second submit.

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, server side script working fine.i checked before post this question